# How to draw an arrow to the edge of a point

Tags: openlayers

I have two points and want to draw an arrow between them.  I am using OpenLayers2.  The code that creates the points looks like:

```
var pt = new OpenLayers.Symbolizer.Point({
    fillColor: color,
    ....[other settings here]....
    pointRadius: radius
});
```

And I create a linestring between them and then create an arrow at point 2.

```
var angle = this.calculateAngle(pt1[0], pt1[1], pt2[0], pt2[1]);

var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(pt2[0], pt2[1]);
point.transform(coreMap.Map.SOURCE_PROJECTION,
    coreMap.Map.DESTINATION_PROJECTION);

var featureArrow = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(point);

OpenLayers.Renderer.symbol.arrow = [0,0, 0,arrowWidth, (arrowWidth / 2),(arrowWidth - 7), arrowWidth,arrowWidth, 0,arrowWidth];

featureArrow.style = new OpenLayers.Symbolizer.Point({
     strokeWidth: 1,
    graphicName: "arrow",
    ...[other settings here]...        
    rotation: angle,
    strokeLinecap: "round"
});
```

This all works, except when the radius of point 2 is large, then the arrow points to the middle of pt2 and is hidden by the Point.  What I want is to have the arrow point to the edge of Point.  If I was in a Cartesian 2D plane without scaling, I could just slide the arrow towards pt1 (since I know the angle) by radius.  However, pt1 and pt2 are of course in lat/lon, and radius is in pixels.  How do I adjust the location of the arrow so that it points at the correct location (edge of the [possibly large] Point)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using map.getExtent() and map.maxPx you can determine the amount to subtract from where your arrow ends.

```
map.getExtent()
```

Will find visible bounding box of your map.

```
map.maxPx()
```

Will give you the number of map pixels.
If we wanted to find the offset from the radius from your feature for latitude you can simply...

```
var y = map.getExtent().top-map.getExtent().bottom;
var diffY = y / map.maxPx.y * feature.radius;
correctedArrowEnd = oldArrowEnd.y - diffY;
```

And do the same for the x value.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer;  this is great.